# process exited with code 1 (0x00000001) after updating wsl

Tags: updates, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a question. I am currently on wsl2 and there is an update to wsl. So I typed wsl.exe --update and updated the wsl system but at the end it said [process exited with code 1 (0x00000001)] . Should it be like that? I am doing this on windows terminal. I updated the wsl from the terminal on which I have the ubuntu distro installed, not from the powershell level, but it seems to me that it's not a problem. What could be causing this? Is this an error?

Comment: getting the same error after updating WSL to `1.2.5.0` completely randomly. E.g. while trying to install some `pip` packages...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exit code 0x1 is indeed an error as you can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-).

A brief research on my side suggests that this is just an issue with displaying output on the command line. There is a report on this behavior [here](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/89).
So, if your wsl2 is working, I wouldn't be too worried about this error code.